# Sequential search takes o(n^2) time. Want it to be either O(1) or O(log n)

Tags: search, python-3.x, big-o

I have a list which contains strings NOT IN SORTED ORDER. Hence, cannot use binary search. My requirement is that each item must find its next occurrence. i.e in the given list, at the time of processing, the first item will search its next occurence (second last item), and so on.

```
[
    "/Users/Rash/Downloads/file1.txt", "/Users/Rash/Downloads/file2.txt",
    "/Users/Rash/Downloads/Programs/File1.txt", "/Users/Rash/Downloads/file1.txt",
    "/Users/Rash/Downloads/file2.txt"
]
```

My code is:

```
for item in mylist:
    process(item, nextOccurrenceOfItem)
```

In the above code, notice that I have to pass "nextOccurrenceOfItem". So, I need to search the list. If I do sequential search, the time that it will take is:

```
n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 2 + 1 = n(n+1)/2 =~ O(n^2)
```

I want some python function that searches in less time, more like O(1) or O(log n).
The list is too large, like 1000 entries in it. Hence a lesser search time algorithm is needed.

I could have also maintained a sorted list, and could have used python's bisect functions in conjunction with binary array, and could have done binary sorting, but maintaining that list is yet another headache, not to mention they will hog up memory because the list is large.

I was also wondering if there is a way to do this search in O(1) time, and is provided by python ?

I am using python3.4

Comment: _"not to mention they will hog up memory because the list is large"_. A thousand elements doesn't sound too large to me. If it's a list of ints, that's like two kilobytes. Most computers can spare that much.

Comment: @Kevin but the list will grow in size as more users use my app. I just gave an estimate. I really don't know how many. I frankly just fear that one day the list will grow too large..

Comment: @Bathsheba is there a python provided algo that searches in O(n). Could give me a link that I can see ?

Comment: Do you have the ability to preprocess the list, and/or the strings?

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis yes I can preprocess them..

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis I think I might have misled u a bit. I meant was that I can maintain a separate list that is preprocessed. The main-list order needs to be maintained.

Thank You all for putting some links to the related answers. I am in the process of understanding them, and will let you guys know if I won't be able to figure out an answer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to make what is essentially a `linked list` (LL) for each unique element in the main list. You also use a dictionary to map each element to it's "linked list". You can build the data structure in `O(N)` and finding the next (or previous in case you need it later) element is `O(1)`.

If you need to change the main list without rebuild the data structure, then you should use a `binary search tree (BST)` (a treemap to more accurate) for `O(N log N)` build and `O(log N)` next/previous query. Changing an element, `E` at index `i`, to `B` then becomes removing `i` from the LL for `E` and adding `i` to the LL for `B`, which costs `O(log N)`.

Each item in the linked list (or BST) represents an index in the main list. The next item in the linked list is the next index where that element appears.

The Python code would look something like this (best implemented as a class, used functions for simplicity). Linked list implementation left as exercise.

```
def create_data_structure(iterable):
    data = {}
    for (index,item) in enumerate(iterable):
        if item not in data: 
            data[item] = linked_list(index) # Index is first node
        else:
            data[item].append(index) # Index is last node
    return data

data = create_data_structure(my_list)
for i,item in enumerate(mylist):
    process(item, mylist[data[item][i].next()])
```